# How can i get URL(links) behind the clickable text using Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
session.trust_env = False
url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams'
response = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


teams = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'small-column-left'})

for team in teams:
    name = team.get_text().strip()
    schedule_url = team.get('a[href]')

 print(name)
```

i get the result as
Atlanta Hawks

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Charlotte Hornets

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Miami Heat

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Orlando Magic

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Washington Wizards

Roster | Schedule | Stats: https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Atlanta-Hawks/1/Home
Northwest Division

Denver Nuggets

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Minnesota Timberwolves

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Oklahoma City Thunder

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Portland Trail Blazers

Roster | Schedule | Stats

Utah Jazz

Roster | Schedule | Stats: https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Denver-Nuggets/7/Home
Pacific Division

but i want url for schedule only which are behind the clickable text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

So select your elements more specific for example with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
[(t.parent.a.text,'https://basketball.realgm.com'+t.get('href')) for t in soup.select('.basketball a[href*="Schedule"]')]
```

##### Exmaple

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
session.trust_env = False

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams'
response = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


[(t.parent.a.text,'https://basketball.realgm.com'+t.get('href')) for t in soup.select('.basketball a[href*="Schedule"]')]
```

##### Output

```
['https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Boston-Celtics/2/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Brooklyn-Nets/38/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/New-York-Knicks/20/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Philadelphia-Sixers/22/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Toronto-Raptors/28/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Chicago-Bulls/4/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Cleveland-Cavaliers/5/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Detroit-Pistons/8/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Indiana-Pacers/11/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Milwaukee-Bucks/16/Schedule/2023',
 'https://basketball.realgm.com/nba/teams/Atlanta-Hawks/1/Schedule/2023',...]
```

---

EDIT

Based on additionally comment, simply create a `list` of `dicts` and convert it to `dataframe`:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [{'team':t.parent.a.text,'url':'https://basketball.realgm.com'+t.get('href')} for t in soup.select('.basketball a[href*="Schedule"]')]
)
```

Comment: Superb Answer Champ, but i was expecting team name as a title in one column and urls in another column, can we do that ? and how we can save this data in excel

Comment: Then this expectation should ideally also be a compulsory part of your question or  you are [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus. Check the edit of my answer for a hint. May take a minute or two to take the [tour], read [ask] to get a better picture how things should work at so. would be great thanks